# NSDateFormatter Incompatible Type Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdateformatter

I am receiving the following error in Xcode:

warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSDate *', expected 'struct NSString *' when passing argument 1 of 'setUpdate:' from distinct Objective-C type

The error happens when I am trying to save the formatted string to myObj.update

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
//myObj is an object with instance variable 'update' as a NSString string
myObj.update = [formatter dateFromString:@"2011-03-17T18:15:05Z"];
[formatter release];
```

I know I am doing something wrong that is minor but can't pinpoint.  Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dateFromString:` returns an instance of `NSDate`, not a string. You need to make your `update` property an `NSDate`. The compiler is basically telling you that the method is returning a date, but you're trying to assign that to a string property, and that's just not gonna be healthy!

Comment: Haha the irony, I saw the error myself and fixed to NSDate in Xcode...come back to SO and see your reply.  thanks Jason :)  Have a nice weekend.